# How are two unequal applied forces at the end of a massless string result in a constant tension throughout?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Even when we apply two different forces $(F_1 > F_2)$ at the ends of an ideal rope, the tension produced in the rope is constant throughout the length of the string rather than being a function of its length. I can't understand this concept, I mean taking any arbitrary element in the rope the element would be experiencing two unequal forces at its two ends so how does that make a common tension? Why is tension not equal to the net resultant force $(F_1 - F_2)$? Is tension different than a force?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536998/2451

Answer (score 2):

If the rope is "light", then it is not possible to apply unequal forces to the ends.  Unequal forces imply acceleration.  And if the mass is approximately zero, the acceleration is huge.   The forces on each end and the tension within are all equal.

If you consider the rope to have mass, then unequal forces are possible, but only if the rope accelerates.  The tension throughout the rope is not equal because the mass that any section of the rope is pulling on to accelerate differs from one side to the other.

Comment: Do check out atwood's machine , that consists of a massless ideal rope having two different masses at the two ends across the pullley, but still has the same tension. Please help

Comment: Just because there are different masses does not mean that there are different forces at each end.  The masses are accelerating, so that suggests that the force from the rope does not equal the weight of the mass.

Comment: Yes you are right but i seriously can't imagine the forces that are acting on any arbitrary element in the string during this situation

Comment: Can you expand on your difficulty?  If you try to put unequal forces on a light object, it accelerates until the forces are equal.  Imagine trying to apply a 10N force to a grain of sand.  You can't do it because it accelerates away too quickly.  Similarly, you can't apply unequal forces to a "sufficiently light" object.