# If A and B are two persons at the end of an ideal rope, where A is applying a force of 70N and B is applying force of 60N then what is the force on A?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

So according to me in this situation there are two forces acting on A at the moment, one is the reactive force of 70 N by newton's third law and the other is the force of 60 N exerted by B. Now don't you think the tension should be the sum of the two pulling forces experienced by A (i.e. 70+60=130 N)...Please tell me where my thinking process is going wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tension of rope. Different Answers?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144407/)

Comment: @James not exactly

Comment: You've now asked 5 questions on this topic, and aren't happy with the answers. That's fair enough, but I strongly suggest that you do some relevant experiments. Theory is important, but the foundation of physics is empirical evidence from observation & experiment. So get yourself a couple of [spring balances](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/spring-balance-white-background-illustration-167445263.jpg), some string, some weights, and some pulleys (or smooth hooks to pass the string over), and do some experiments.

Comment: @PM2Ring Well why do you sound so rude...if you don't wanna answer then it's your wish ...no one is forcing you...but sorry i can't relax unless and until i get my concepts clear..thank you

Comment: Sorry, CuriousMind, I didn't mean to sound rude. I even said that it's fair enough that you aren't happy with the answers you've been given so far. But I think it will be helpful for you to get some literal hands-on experience with this stuff by doing these experiments. It certainly helped me when I was learning this stuff.

Comment: @PM2Ring  no no don't be sorry...that's where today's educational system lags...everyone is after cramming....very few are their who really love to feel the beauty of the subject... i think its a big failure on teachers' side that they often forget to give the practical feel of the subject to their students!

Answer (score 0):

> Please tell me where my thinking process is going wrong.

Your thinking is going wrong because it violates Newton’s 3rd law. If A is applying a force of 70 N on the rope then by Newton’s 3rd law the rope is applying a force of -70 N on A. That is it. Any other value violates Newton’s 3rd law.

The force exerted by B acts on the rope, not on A.

Comment: But the rope is connecting A and B, if B is pulling A with 60 N then this force must be transfered to A as tension

Comment: That is not necessary, and since it would violate Newton’s laws it doesn’t happen. Instead there is a 10 N net force on the rope so it accelerates.

Comment: Hence what will be the tension of the rope in my case?

Comment: The tension will be non uniform in the rope. It will be 70 N near A and 60 N near B. This is what happens when a rope accelerates. This is the same as when a rope is hanging in gravity where the top will have more tension than the bottom due to the top holding up the mass of the rest of the rope while the bottom is only holding its own mass.

Comment: And what if i say the rope is massless as is generally assumed?

Comment: Then it is impossible to have A exert 70 N and B exert 60 N. For your scenario to be physically possible the rope must have mass and it must accelerate.

Comment: Please check out atwood's machine(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atwood_machine
) wherein we have used two unequal weights along a massless rope and still we get same tension throughout the string

Comment: I am not sure why you think that is a counterexample. The forces on both ends of the massless rope are the same, as I said.

Comment: No just see the fig. in the link i have provided(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atwood_machine
) the two weights hanging on either side of the pulley are unequal....if there were equal weights on either side in that case non should have accelerated

Comment: The weights are unequal but the forces they exert on the rope are equal.

Comment: @Dale:  See my discussion with OP at his other question.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/536791/why-does-the-tension-in-a-rope-change-when-the-system-sets-into-motion-from-rest

Comment: How come that be possible i mean the force that they are applying must be equal to their gravitational weights..

Comment: @Achintya Gulati I am done here. Sorry. I am getting the “comments are not for discussion” warning so I don’t want to continue. Plus this is a closed topic so it won’t get any votes. If you want to have a discussion (instead of just an answer) then you need to go to a discussion forum, like physicsforums.com  This site is just not intended for discussion.

Comment: okay thank you for your time